# Loading JSON file in Xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin

I am using the following code to load JSON file in Xamarin. The JSON file is a simple file containing name and age of one person.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("First_json.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    P1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
    //MessageBox.Show(P1.name);
}
```

The code was working correctly in c# but in Xamarin while using `StreamReader` the error pops up saying unable to convert string to stream argument. I have searched the internet to find a better way to read the file but I haven't succeeded so far.

Comment: This Code works in Xamarin.
At which Line do you get this Message?
And what is P1?

Comment: I get the excpetion thrown out at when I try to deseralize Json. Json reads out to be "First_Json.json" instead of the content of json file. 
P1 is the object of class Person. The class is as follows:
 public class Person
        {
            public string name;
            public int age;

        }
The contents of my Json file are: 
{
  "Name": "Umer",
  "Age": 5
}

Comment: Can you please paste the exact Exception Text here?

Comment: Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: F. Path ", line 0, position 0.

Comment: As I mentioned before the first error pops up when I try to give the file name directly in stream reader constructor. Thats why I am now using the following code to first convert the file name to stream type.

 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First_Json.json");
           
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

  StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream);
                
   string json = r.ReadToEnd();
  P1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);

Comment: as I said, the code above will work (for iOS).
Make sure you are not mixing namespaces (try explicitly: System.IO.StreamReader r = new System.IO.StreamReader("First_json.json"))

The Exception Message you posted is another thing. try to validate the json with an online validator.

Comment: The JSON file is correct. It was working correctly in C# windows forms application. The problem started when I tried to make cross platform application using Xamarin Portable Class Library.

Comment: A description / screenshot of your file structure could help. And also what BuildAction is set on the .json file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add the JSON file into the Asset folder of your project

sample : `{"Age":30,"Name":"testuser"}`

and read like this

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("First_json.txt")))
{
    var jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var questionsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide your First_json file with extension as .json "First_json.json".

Your class should be like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now it will work. Let me know your result.